# I am not able to create pipeline for SSR nextjs produciton

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

here is my pipeline steps:-

    `export buildName=$(Build.BuildNumber)
    echo $buildName
    export buildnumber=${buildName/{PROJECTNAME}/1.0.}
    echo $buildnumber
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag;]'$buildnumber
    cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    npm install
    npm run build
    rm -r node_modules
    npm install --production`

please help me to speedup nextjs SSR

Comment: Why are not you able? Any more details?

Comment: when i check in local machine it is working perfectly with extreme speed but after that i added the code into server and run this pipeline. i am not getting that much speed and performance